# WCF newbie - is FaultException<T> safe for non-.NET clients?

Tags: wcf

WCF Newbie alert.  I'm reading "Learning WCF" and "Programming WCF Services" where both books recommend throwing FaultException<T>.  If T is .NET type "DivideByZeroException" and assuming a FaultContract exists with

> [FaultContract(typeof(DivideByZeroException))]

on method "Divide", will a non-.NET client consuming that WCF service and method be able to understand and process that .NET exception?  If yes, is it because the type info (DivideByZeroException) is part of the metadata (because of the FaultContract) that the client has access to and uses?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can throw a `FaultContract<DivideByZeroException>`, but in general you shouldn't do that, exactly for the reason you mentioned (*). What is usually recommended is to have a data contract with the information from the exception, such as the exception message, and then have a `FaultContract` of that type.

```
[DataContract]
public class MyErrorDetails
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

And then use

```
[FaultContract(typeof(MyErrorDetails))]
```

(*) Another reason to avoid returning exceptions as faults is that they disclose more information to the client than the client needs; things such as the stack trace are serialized by the exception, but that's some information internal to the service and shouldn't be sent to clients.

Comment: I'm trying to verify your answer.  In "Programming WCF Services" p.208 under "Faults" it says:`The fundamental problem with exceptions is that they are technology-specific and as such should not be shared across the service boundary.  For seamless interoperability, you need a way to map technology-specific exceptions to some neutral error information.  This representation is called soap faults.  ...  To throw a soap fault the service cannot throw a raw CLR exception.  Instead, the service should throw an instance of FaultException<T> class, defined in Example 6-1.`  So is FaultException<T> ok?

Comment: Yes. `FaultException<T>` is handled as a special case by the WCF framework - it will only serialize the information which is defined in the fault contract (assuming that you declared a `[FaultContract(typeof(T))]` on your operation), and that information is based on the SOAP standard.

Comment: Appologies Carlos - you and I have the same thread going on msdn, but I'm still not completely clear.  If the wcf service throws a CLR DivideByZeroException, and a FaultContract exists like [FaultContract(typeof(DivideByZeroException))], then is that safe for non-.NET clients?  Your response on msdn makes me think that it is NOT safe since DivideByZeroException is not a safe type (it contains stacktrace and other info that you wouldn't want exposed to a client).  But the quote I copied out of the book in my comment above doesn't say anything about T needing to be a safe type.  Still  confused.

Comment: Are you saying that you technically could use `[FaultContract(typeof(DivideByZeroException))]` and that it **would** be safe for non-.NET clients, but you shouldn't since because T is a CLR exception it will contain stack track and other info that you don't want propagated to the client?  Is that what you're saying?